# set up DERBY_HOME environment variable on mac?

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-plugin, environment-variables, derby

I'm using Eclipse and wish to also use the Derby database and am having a problem setting it up properly.

I copied the plugin files to the Eclipse plugin folder thinking that Derby would show up on the popup menu that has "new", "properties", ect on it but it doesn't show up there.

Someone told me to start the Derby server so I copied the bin folder onto my computer and ran the startNetworkServer unix executable file. It gave me this error:

```
Error: DERBY_HOME is not set. Please set the DERBY_HOME environment variable
to the location of your Derby installation.
```

So can you tell me how to do the steps the error states I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the "Terminal" Application and navigate into your Home directory.

Then add this to the `.bashrc` file:

```
DERBY_HOME=/directory/to/your/installation
export DERBY_HOME
```

If it does not exist, simply create it with `touch .bashrc`